# h box alignment in gtk

Tags: linux, gtk

hi every one i am trying to make a gui. in which i have placed a hbox in my window and 2 hboxes (hbox1 ,hbox2) inside the main hbox. but the problem is that the hbox1 and hbox2 share equal space is there a way through which  i can give more space to hbox1 and less space to hbox2

here is my code

hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE,1);
  hbox1 = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE,1);

hbox2 = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE,1);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hbox),hbox1);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hbox),hbox2);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), hbox);

thanks

Comment: It may helps: [Can someone explain Gtk2 packing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668226/can-someone-explain-gtk2-packing)

Answer (score 3):

This is all explained in the GTK tutorial, in the ["Packing Widgets"](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.24/x363.html) section.